# Types predicate: can 'is' be seen as a subtype of boolean?

Tags: typescript

I was studying better [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) and how they actually narrow the type through `pet is Fish`, for example.

I've tried to create a simple [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLAM4AtkG8CwAUMicputgFzJhQCuEA3EachgO7AC21tDzhAL5EioSLEQoAQsCgATPC1KYZ83vSZFhhIjDogEYYAHsQZDBSwAKAA4Qw1S8gA+yVXICU1O2HNpMOATEyFD2dFBmtvbIcBj+2B4AdBzcyACEALwZyPpyEDCgEHIC2rr6hiZmcsYAysZc9ligAOZRDvE4ru4eisGs-QPIAPRDyAB6APxKJAimGL6YAAr2TtnkAW0eAoPDo5MifWQwyFZLKwE9QTs+0yQj41OH2oJAA)

In `doSomething` I use `isFish` function.
`isFish` is represented to have a return type `pet is Fish`, but if I use it and assign the result to a variable, the result is kinda "casted" to a `boolean`. So I guess `pet is Fish` can be seen as a type itself.

So my question is: can `pet is Fish` (or whatever similar expression) be considered a subtype of boolean, just like `"Hello world"` is a subtype of `string`?

```js
type X = "hello world" | string;
  // ^? type X = string

type Y = "hello world" & string;
  // ^? type Y = "hello world"
```

Thank you!

Comment: the playground is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not really equivalent to const strings. Booleans have only two possible values, i.e. `boolean` is the same as `true | false`, you cannot narrow that type other than having just `true` or `false`.

I would think of type guard as being a special syntax, a function like `isFish(pet: Cat | Dog | Fish): pet is Fish` returns a boolean, and the compiler knows if that boolean is `true` that the `pet` variable is in fact a `Fish`, or if `false` then it is not a `Fish`, and narrows the type of the `pet` variable e.g.:

```js
const pet: Cat | Dog | Fish = getPet();
if (isFish(pet) {
  // pet now has type Fish
} else {
  // pet now has type Cat | Dog
}
```

Comment: I can agree on the fact that it is not equivalent to const strings. But `pet is Fish` feels like gets narrowed to a boolean, but like it has some additional context...

Comment: The type of `pet is Fish` is always just a boolean, the additional context applies to the type of `pet` which is separate from the type of `pet is Fish`